# Inheritance in Silverlight 2 Styles

Tags: xaml, silverlight-2.0, code-reuse, styling

I want to build up styles in XAML, e.g.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,2,2,2" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkRed" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="MyBoldStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource MyStyle}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

But this does not work. (In Silverlight 2)  How can I make one inherit from the other?

---

**June 2010 Update:** [Style Inheritance is in Silverlight 3](http://www.devcurry.com/2010/02/inheriting-style-in-silverlight-3.html), use `BasedOn="{StaticResource MyStyle}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind. I found [the answer](https://books.google.nl/books?id=mY2YWBC_M-8C&pg=PA334&lpg=PA334&dq=silverlight%20style%20inherit%20%22like%20css%22&source=bl&ots=T1C9YFvo4o&sig=MVSAsJBCOs3HjmnNrM8uGvgtc_w&hl=en&ei=muyuSeToKMe_tgfUqdCABg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&redir_esc=y) in MacDonald's [Pro Silverlight 2 in C# 2008](https://web.archive.org/web/20110112083558/http://apress.com/book/view/9781590599495):

[image]
<sub>(source: [apress.com](http://www.apress.com/resource/bookcover/9781590599495?size=medium))</sub>

> "If you've used styles in WPF, you'll find
> that Silverlight styles are
> dramatically scaled back ... [for example, you can't]
> create styles that inherit from other styles."

Too bad.  Maybe in Silverlight 3.

Comment: Yes, it is coming in Silverlight 3 -- http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/03/18/silverlight-3-whats-new-a-guide.aspx#element